Subset from NetCDF4 dataset - How
I have a netCDF4 dataset in python with 3 variables (height, lat, long).
I want all the lat and long values when height is 1.
I understand that is something like generate a new dataset when height is equal to 1, but I can't figure out which commands use, etc after:
import netCDF4

ds = netCDF4.Dataset('height_SO4.nc')


Im looking for something like: ds_h1 = ds[1,:,:]
